# How to get an array repeat in foreach loop

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

This is my $settings array.... and I would like to look this array in foreach so that I can read the `$settings['node']['type'][$value['type']]['modifiers']` values in foreach loop and print them.

Comment: It's not clear from your code and your question what you want to do. Please clarify!

Comment: @Laxman paste your original array and desired array both here

Comment: @diEcho - I have edited my code and updated, plz check and suggest.

Comment: Whats the matter with it? I dont see any question and your description suggest, that you already know, what you can do :?

Comment: paste your desired array in codepad.org i paste your array here `http://codepad.org/qoCVT4aG` u must modify

Comment: @KignCruch - I am not getting the $settings array looped in the foreach statement, what could be the cause ?? I need that to be looped for every foreach count...

Comment: Please provide more info on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm can only guess you want to iterate over each element in your array.

```
foreach($settings as $node=>$types){
    foreach($types as $values=>$modifiers){
      \\ etc etc etc

         echo "Settings: $node $types $values $modifiers";

    }
}
```

Just keep nesting the `foreach` loops for each element you want to iterate.

Comment: Glad you got it working but what do you mean "I took a session"?

Comment: I have created the session for the settings array to use it in the foreach loop...